# MouseInfo getLocation causes JVM crash in java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to run the following program:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + "," + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);
    }
}
```

However, after running it in IntelliJ, the program will just sit there for about 10 seconds and then exit with this:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Most of the google results (and stack overflow posts) related to this error seem to think it is an NVIDIA driver issue, but those posts also state that an updated driver with a fix was posted in February and the driver on my computer is version 382, which is a newer version than the fix posted, so it would have included that fix.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does it work without errors outside of IntelliJ IDEA? Did you try some different Java version?

Comment: I also have a crash in JVM when calling MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(); I have a try/catch around it and it is not an exception, the JVM simply dies. Using Windows 10. Did you find a solution?